# To compute partial derivatives at $(0,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}  {xy^2} \quad \text{when} \ y > 0\\ -xy^2 \quad \text{when} \ y < 0\end{cases}$$

I found value of partial derivative of $x $ to be $ 1$ and $f_y$ to be $0$
 not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because $f(x,y)$ is obviously continuous at $(0,1)$. If considering only $(0,1)$, you can simply ignore the case when $y<0$.

Hence, $f_x = y^2 = 1^2 = 1$ and $f_y = 2xy = 2\cdot0\cdot1 = 0$ at that point.